# iOS - How to set currency and language independent of the device locale

Tags: ios, localization, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

I am trying to develop an app where you can change the currency to one of your choice and same for the language, so all the data will be shown in that currency and language.

For example, I have a screen that shows how much money you have in an account, and that amount is shown by using `NSNumberFormatter`, but I'm not sure if the correct way to show the correct string is by setting each and every `NSNumberFormatter` to the currency that the user has selected in the app preferences.

I thought I can change the locale for the app, but this doesn't seem to be the desired way, or the Apple-recommended way.

Comment: Rather than instantiating your formatters all over the place in your code, have a single utility method that instantiates a `NSNumberFormatter` with the correct locale (either the default locale or something that the user overrode via app settings), and then call that from throughout the app.

Comment: I  do a little research earlier, changing locale in app can be tricky. Can you use a NSString category to do the formatting so that you don't have to deal with NSNumberFormatter every time you need a number with currency?

Comment: I think Rob's opinion could work well, but at the same time, I would like to know what the recommended way is...